# Generate matrices with super simple condition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a matrix $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times d}$ and a vector $x \in \mathbb R^{d \times 1}$ given to me.

I want to generate matrices $W, H \in \mathbb R^{d \times d}$ of rank $1$ and vectors $u, v \in \mathbb R^{n \times 1}$ such that

$W = A^Tux^TH^T$ and $H = W^TA^Tvx^T$

I'm having trouble doing this since I need to choose them all "at the same time". Anyone has any idea or an example of this setting?

Comment: "super simple" is neither exact nor useful in your title...

Comment: My apologies Jean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us write the equations:

$$W = A^Tux^TH^T \tag{1}$$

$$H = W^TA^Tvx^T \tag{2}$$

where we can assume without loss of generality that $x^Tx=1$.

Plugging (2) into (1) gives:

$$W=(A^Tu\underbrace{x^Tx}_1v^TA)W$$

$$W=\underbrace{(A^Tu)}_{p}\underbrace{(A^Tv)^T}_{q^T}W\tag{3}$$

Let us right (3) under the following form:

$$\begin{pmatrix}|&|&&|\\w_1&w_2&\cdots&w_d \\ |&|&&|\end{pmatrix}=pq^T \begin{pmatrix}|&|&&|\\w_1&w_2&\cdots&w_d \\ |&|&&|\end{pmatrix}$$

Otherwise said:

$$\forall i=1 \cdots d, \ \ w_i=pq^T w_i$$

meaning that $w_i$ is an eigenvector of rank-one matrix $pq^T$ associated with eigenvalue $\color{red}{1}$.

But the eigenpairs of this rank-one matrix are well-known (see theorem $1$ in [this document](https://www.emis.de/journals/BJGA/v10n1/B10-1-OSN.pdf)); they are:

$$\begin{cases}\text{eigenvalues : }&(p^Tq, 0, 0, \cdots 0) \ \ \text{associated with}\\
\text{eigenvectors : }&(p,k_1,k_2, \cdots k_{d-1}) \  \text{resp.}\end{cases}$$

where the $k_i$ constitute any basis of the $(d-1)$-dimensional space orthogonal to $p:=A^Tu$ (which is the kernel of $p^Tq$).

Therefore, as all the $w_i$ have to be associated to nonzero eigenvalue, we have $w_i=p$, meaning that

$$W=[p,p,\cdots p]=[A^Tu,A^Tu,\cdots A^Tu], \tag{4}$$

that we can write as well:

$$W=p\mathbb{1}^T=A^T[u,u,\cdots,u]=A^Tu\mathbb{1}^T$$

where $\mathbb{1}$ is the column vedtor with all entries equal to $1$.

This identification can be done under the condition that the nonzero eigenvalue has the value $\color{red}{1}$:

$$p^Tq=1$$

which is equivalent to:

$$u^TAA^Tv=1 \tag{5}$$

((5) is called a "conjugation relationship" in the framework of conics or quadrics).

**Practical conclusion:** take $u,v$ to be any pair satisfying (5) (there is a large degree of freedom for that!), then $W$ is given by relationship (4). $H$ is then obtained from (2).

Comment: Could you say something about the origin of the problem ?

Comment: I wouldn't know actually, a friend challenged me. I have an issue with your answer, maybe I don't completely understand. $k_1, k_2$ etc are eigenvectors with eigenvalue zero. We won't have $W = pq^TW$ if we use them, as we'll have zero on one side and the eigenvector on the other. Not to mention $W$ will be of the wrong rank. I agree with the eigenvector of value $1$ though. The other columns however need to be some multiple of it.

Comment: First, thank you. Forgive me, it is late. Secondly, suppose for the sake of simplicity that $d=2$. If I understood you correctly, initially you suggested to choose $W = [A^Tu, k_1]$. My problem with that is $pq^Tk_1 = 0$ so on LHS we have $[A^Tu, k_1]$ and on RHS we have $[A^Tu, 0]$. Your second suggestion (in comments) is different.

Comment: Thanks ! I am going to answer you. I see, there is a problem. I am going to fix it.

Comment: I tried writing a simple python script that tests this with the 0 vector suggestion. It works sometimes, other times it doesn't. As in the $W$ isn't equal to what we want. Interesting that it sometimes works, this isn't a fluke this is the correct direction but not entirely accurate.

Comment: I have made a "first aid" correction. I was wrong $\iff$  you were right. Tell me if the Python script works well now.

Comment: Thanks! perfect.

Comment: Happy end. Sorry for the error.

Comment: Actually...wow this is interesting. Again it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't. Maybe its due to numerical errors when computing the eigenvector

Comment: In fact, I see another issue. The way I have written the solution is that I give a solution that works but in fact, as an eigenvector is defined up to a (same) multiplicative constant $W=\alpha[p,p,\cdots p]$... Isn't it there that we have a discrepancy ?

Comment: Could be. Your choice of using $p$ is arbitrary. $2p, 3p, -17p$ and heck even $0$ as you suggested also fit the bill of $pq^TW = W$. Should they all lead to $W = A^Tux^TH^T$?

Comment: Yes in fact this $\alpha$ doesn't bring a supplementary degree of freedom. Have you seen the way one can write $W$ with a vector of ones ? As it is late here (past midnight CET, maybe the same for you), we can talk again tomorrow. Good night.

Comment: Good night Jean, thanks for your input and the discussion. I'll be sure to check back here tomorrow if you or I have anything wise to say.